# How docker volume mounts differ

Tags: docker, jenkins, volume, docker-volume

Please look at the following output.

```sh
docker run -it --rm ireshmm/jenkins:lts-jdk11 ls -la /var/jenkins_home
```

Output:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 22 16:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     4096 Jan 12 15:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  4683 Jan 22 16:20 copy_reference_file.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 16384 Jan 22 16:20 plugins
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jenkins root     7152 Jan 12 15:42 tini_pub.gpg
```

When we mount a fresh new volume at /var/jenkins_home,

```sh
docker run -v random_volume:/var/jenkins_home -it --rm ireshmm/jenkins:lts-jdk11 ls -la /var/jenkins_home
```

Output:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 22 16:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     4096 Jan 12 15:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  4683 Jan 22 16:24 copy_reference_file.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 16384 Jan 22 16:24 plugins
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jenkins root     7152 Jan 12 15:42 tini_pub.gpg
```

**Question**: How do the files still exist? Shouldn't they be gone?

When we mount a empty directory on host,

```
mkdir /tmp/empty_dir && chmod 777 /tmp/empty_dir
docker run -v /tmp/empty_dir:/var/jenkins_home -it --rm ireshmm/jenkins:lts-jdk11 ls -la /var/jenkins_home
```

Output:

```
total 32
drwxrwxrwx 3    1001    1001  4096 Jan 22 16:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     4096 Jan 12 15:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  4683 Jan 22 16:28 copy_reference_file.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 16384 Jan 22 16:28 plugins
```

**Question**: Why do the output differ from the previous output? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

This is described [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container):

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume. The container then mounts and uses the volume, and other containers which use the volume also have access to the pre-populated content.

Bind mounts don't share this behavior.

Comment: Furthermore, if the underlying image is updated, the older content in a Docker named volume will take precedence.  In not-quite-Docker environments, Kubernetes PersistentVolumes and other mounts don't share this behavior.  I'd avoid relying on the copy-on-first-use behavior.